# ¿Por qué Pepe es equivalente a José?

Tags: etimología, nombres-propios

El nombre José puede tener distintos diminutivos: Jose (¿sin tilde?)... y Pepe.

Leí en alguna ocasión que Pepe es un [hipocorístico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipocor%C3%ADstico) (*apelativos cariñosos, familiares o eufemísticos usados para suplantar a un nombre real*) que viene de la creencia que José de Nazaret era el *Padre Putativo* de Jesús, por lo que se fuera contrayendo hasta PP → Pepe.

Sin embargo, [hay artículos](http://www.abc.es/sociedad/20140319/abci-porque-jose-pepe-201403190741.html) que indican que puede haber otras teorías.

De ahí que me pregunte: ¿hay alguna certeza sobre el origen de la equivalencia entre Pepe y José?

Comment: Un hipocorístico no es un diminutivo. Por ejemplo el de *Ramón* es *moncho* pero podemos decir *ramoncito* para decir el diminutivo, no necesariamente *monchito*.

Comment: @Ale tienes razón, edité para corregirlo.

Comment: @Alejandro Moncho puede venir de "Ramoncho", pero lo de pepe sí que parece absolutamente inconexo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según el artículo, sólo parece haber dos teorías. Yo había leído únicamente acerca de la primera, y lo que recuerdo de ella es que "P P" por *pater putativus* se escribía en las catacumbas cristianas porque era menos riesgoso en tiempos de persecución. La segunda teoría no creo que deba estar muy reñida con la primera, ya que supongo que el italiano *Beppe* o *Peppe* podría tranquilamente derivar de "P P". Lo cierto es que jamás vi una foto de una catacumba o de un misal que dijera "P P", aunque tampoco la busqué. Pero lo que me resultó interesante fue que, según dice el [artículo de Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepe),

> ...en castellano no se ha podido aún documentar pues, según el CORDE,
>   "Pepe" no aparece con este uso hasta el siglo XVIII.

Luego de enterarme de qué era el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html), procedí a darle una mirada y, efectivamente, las [primeras menciones](https://books.google.com/books?id=rKsGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA310#v=onepage&q&f=false) de *Pepe* son de esas fechas; al parecer, las [más antiguas](https://archive.org/stream/becerrogticode03card#page/124/mode/2up) hacen referencia al nombre franco Pipino y sus equivalentes (Riesco, [*Anotaciones toponímicas salmantinas*](http://www.upo.es/ghf/giest/documentos/otros/Riesco2006_anotacionestoponimicassalmantinas.pdf), p. 258). Igual, es la primera vez que consulto el CORDE así que seguramente habrá más y mejores explicaciones que esta.

Comment: El famoso "Pepe" Botella nació con el nombre de Giuseppe Napoleone Buonaparte. De Giuseppe a Pepe hay un paso.

Comment: En algún lugar leí que a los Franciscos se les dice Paco porque San Francisco de Asís era el _Pater Comunitatis_ o padre de la comunidad Franciscana.  Es una teoría similar a la de _pater putativus_

Answer (score 3):

Joseph, Jose and Giuseppe are variants of the same name. Somehow Pepe, the diminutive of the Italian version (Giuseppe), migrated to the Spanish version (Jose) possibly during the Spanish occupation of southern Italy when the 2 populations and languages intermingled.

The above is supported by [http://spanishlinguist.us](http://spanishlinguist.us/2013/03/pepe-and-paco-2-mysterious-spanish-nicknames/) who `[...] turned to the ultimate source, querying the Real Academia Española through its on-line consultation service.`

> [The] nickname **Pepe comes, in reality, from the Italian Beppe, itself a nickname for Giuseppe**….In the case of Paco, none of the data on names that we have at our disposal support the etymology of pater comunitatis.

Comment: Do you have a reference to back that up?