# Why is "Paco" the equivalent of "Francisco"?

Tags: etimología, nombres-propios, contracciones

In Spain it is quite common to use the hypocoristic *Paco* to refer to the people with the name *Francisco*.

Why is that? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco) states that:

> In Spanish, people with the name Francisco sometimes are nicknamed
>   "Paco": San Francisco de Asís was known as Pater Comunitatis (The
>   Community father) when he founded the Franciscan order, "Paco" is a
>   short form of "Pater Comunitatis".

But there is no reference to this fact and I wonder if this is another built-up story related to [¿Por qué Pepe es equivalente a José?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15462/1674) with *Pater Putativus*.

Note, as seen in comments, that also *Pacho* (in Colombia) and *Pancho* (in Chile, among others) are used as hypocoristics to Francisco.

Comment: The _Pater Comunitatis_ story is the same I heard before but it is even more curious when you think that around latin america we do not use _Paco_ but **Pacho**

Comment: @DGaleano I think you mean **Pancho** :)

Comment: @VladimirNu I don't think so. I've met some **Pacho**s in Colombia. Pancho is another hypocoristic, as well. So now we already have three: Paco,  Pacho and Pancho : )

Comment: Totally off-topic, but in Chile *paco* is a short name for cop, which is *carabinero*.

Comment: @fedorqui Nice to know.

Comment: @VladimirNu oh, interesting! [In Spain they are called _maderos_](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14750/1674) and I see [paco has tons of meanings in DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RPxdjMe|RQ3rtmp|RQ4TNbp|RQ4rQf6|RQ5T4Ke).

Comment: @fedorqui I confirmed that. I have a venezuelan friend (Francisco, by the way) who just told me that there they use **Pancho** as well, but some friends from him (also from Venezuela) call him **Pacho**, he believes because they have family in Colombia and live close to the border.

Comment: @VladimirNu I thing that in Chile we tell the cops _pacos_ because in colonial times was a famous guard named Francisco.

Comment: @VladimirNu I'm wrong. In [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?paco) there are several theories about the origin of our Chilean _pacos_.

Comment: Another hypochoristic for Francisco is **Curro** (at least in Spain), and I don't think it also comes from _Pater Comunitatis_.

Comment: La verdad que hasta ahora lo veo el porque del acronimo bueno para darte más datos en mi país El Salvador se usa el deciles Chepe a los que se llaman José.

Comment: @VladimirNu, en the tropical region of Bolivia cops are called "pacos" as well. I was always curious about this. There is a chance that the nickname comes from your country (now, is this valid for the whole Chile, or just some regions?). Glad you brought the _offTopic_

Comment: @DelonixR. It's used in all the country. It's not polite to call a cop that way, by the way, but everyone use this in colloquial.

Comment: Hi @VladimirNu, just like in my hometown, Santa Cruz de la Sierra. You never call a cop: "Mr. Paco"...lol!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Amando de Miguel briefly states some theories in this [article](http://www.libertaddigital.com/opinion/amando-de-miguel/onomastica-31350/). I tend to favour the one pointing at the abbreviation of *Phranciscus* (the latinised version of Francisco de Asís's nickname) as *Ph.co* in signs and inscriptions. This explains *Paco* which, relaxing the /k/ sound, becomes *Pacho* and, mixing this with the original n in the full name, gives *Pancho*. Versions in other language, such as the Aragonese *Francho* or the Italian *Franco*, can be explained also through abbreviation, including or not the relaxation of the /k/ sound.

The blog post [¿Cómo se llega de Francisco a Paco?](http://www.alsurdelafrontera.es/2015/02/como-se-llega-de-francisco-a-paco/) expands a bit on the explanation, adding an interesting parallel between the proposed *Ph.co* or *Phco* and the current *Fco.*, which we use in names such as *Francisco Javier* (usually abbreviated nowadays as *Fco. Javier* in writing).

Comment: From the moment this question was asked I've thought that it was going to be something about the abbreviation of the name. I'm an amateur genealogist, and I've seen a lot of birth records of people named Francisco, abbreviated to Franc.o (with the _o_ as an exponent). Those records were from the XVII century, and I supposed that a previous abbreviation should be the origin of Paco).

Comment: Even more orthographic changes come from the diminutive _Paquito_, which I have found more often in feminine _Paquita_ and finally shortened _Paqui_.

Answer (score 9):

In brief: I think the evolution from Francisco to Paco, Pacho and Pancho obeys the same mechanisms observed in other hipocorystics, probably related to child pronunciation or imitation of this one for emotional reasons.

With Chilean examples, there are other hypocoristics where a **F** is changed by a **P**:

- Al**f**onso - **P**oncho
- **F**elipe - **P**ipe
- Jose**f**a - Che**p**a
- **F**rancisco - **P**ancho

And where the **R** sound is deleted or replaced:

- Federico - <del>Rico</del> - Quico
- Mercedes - <del>Merche</del> - Meche
- Beatriz - <del>Betri</del> - Beti
- Patricio - <del>Patro</del> - Pato
- Victoria - <del>Toria</del> - Toya
- Sergio - <del>Chercho</del> - Checho
- Francisco - <del>Fraco</del> - Paco

And in which the word length is shortened to **two syllables** (this includes all the previous examples):

- Florencio - Floro
- Alejandro - Jano
- Eduardo - Yayo
- Vicente - Vicho
- Rodrigo - Rorro
- Francisco - Paco

And where the accent position in the word shortened is changed to the **first syllable**:

- Catalina - Cata
- José - Cote
- Gabriel - Gabo
- Victoria - Viqui
- Mauricio - Mauro