# ¿Por qué "Concha" es diminutivo de Concepción?

Tags: etimología, historia, nombres-propios, diminutivos, contracciones

Según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepci%C3%B3n_%28nombre%29):

> "Concha" se utiliza como diminutivo del nombre propio Concepción, igual que Conchita, Conchi (y con pronunciaciones similares aunque ligeramente distinta escritura en italiano, por ej: Conccia', Concetta). En el dialecto rioplatense al ser malsonante la palabra «concha» (palabra que en casi todo el Cono Sur alude a la vulva y a la vagina) era común usar para las mujeres llamadas Concepción el hipocorístico: Cochona.

La definición actual de [concha](https://dle.rae.es/?id=A81xUaG) no recoge ese uso, y en cambio si recoge la acepción

> 12. f. malson. *Arg., Bol., Chile, Guat., Par., Perú y Ur.* **coño** (‖ vulva y vagina).

Buscando en el [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUIMenuNtlle?cmd=Lema&sec=1.2.0.0.0.) he encontrado que la acepción "Concha = nombre propio equivalente a Concepción" aparece en varios diccionarios del periodo **1846 - 1869** (Salvá 1846, RAE 1852, Castro y Rossi 1852, no en Dominguez 1853 ni en Gaspar y Roig 1853, si en RAE 1869 y en Dominguez (suplemento) 1869), para luego desaparecer completamente.

En el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html), acotando la búsqueda para España y los años 1840 y 1880 apenas he hallado alguna referencia en que Concha fuera nombre de mujer, como en

> Pues ¡cómo... Qué tiene usted?...
>   Y **Concha** la habla al oido
>   Y le dice... no sé qué. (Bretón de los Herreros, *Poesías*, 1828-1870)

o

> ... las señoritas Baldomera Cruz, **Concha Mariátegui**, Luisa Zárate ... (Mesonero Romanos, *Memorias de un setentón*, 1880-1881)

¿Por qué ese diminutivo?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el DLE no recoge los nombres propios ni los hipocorísticos. Por ejemplo, en [_pepe_](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SVbfpvb) no se recoge su uso como "José".

Comment: En México concha no es mala palabra ni significa lo que los pervertidos piensan. Y si sigue existiendo el nombre de Concepción y se les dice de cariño Concha o Conchita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para complementar a [la respuesta de @ukemi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28086/12637), comentar que el propio término *hipocorístico* [proviene](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KT69on7) del griego *ὑποκοριστικός hypokoristikós* 'acariciador'. Según Corominas, este a su vez deriva de *kypokorizomai* 'yo hablo a la manera de los niños' o, según el diccionario Alemany y Bolufer de 1917, "halagar a un niño imitando su lenguage".

Es pues común que estos apodos se formen de modo que resulten fáciles de pronunciar para los más pequeños. He estado buscando y parece ser que los sonidos *ch*, *s* y *z* son similares en cuanto a dificultad de aprendizaje del español, pudiéndose dominar [sobre los 4 o 5 años](https://www.guiainfantil.com/articulos/salud/lenguaje/a-que-edad-pronuncian-los-ninos-cada-letra/). Yo como padre diría que el sonido *ch* es algo más fácil, y además tiene la particularidad de que hace las palabras más sonoras y divertidas. También recuerdo haber hablado al respecto con gente de otros países, por ejemplo una vez me contaron que en Japón los niños aprenden a pronunciar la *s* de las últimas, siendo esta sustituida en muchas ocasiones por el sonido *ch*. Y en [artículos en inglés](https://kids-first.com.au/what-sounds-should-your-child-be-able-to-say) leo que los sonidos *s* y *ch* se pronuncian sobre los 5 años mientras que el sonido *th* (el equivalente a la *c* en *Mercedes*) sobre los 7.

Esto explicaría los cambios comentados por ukemi (Pancho, Merche), dado que al introducir la *ch* como sustituto de la segunda *c* en Concepción, la palabra se hace más sonora y fácil de pronunciar, y luego simplemente se acorta la palabra. Así resultaría *Conche*, pero imagino que por influencia de *concha* que ya existía previamente el hipocorístico quedaría con esa forma, que además refleja mejor el femenino del nombre.

---

Como curiosidad, buscando en registros históricos el registro más antiguo que he encontrado de alguien llamado Concha es un censo de 1854 de Alcoy (Alicante), de una tal Concha Jordá. Debía ser ampliamente conocida por ese apodo si la registraron así en el censo en vez de como Concepción. Hay varias Conchas también en un censo de 1875 de Sevilla. En ese mismo censo hay también alguna que otra Conche. En 1887 aparece una Concheta Plaja en un registro de Girona, seguramente la versión catalana de Conchita, que aparece también en registros hacia finales del siglo XIX. Por contra, el nombre Concetta aparece en registros italianos a partir de la primera mitad del siglo XVIII.

Comment: Qué respuesta tan fantástica. _Concetta_ la encontré hace poco en _El Gatopardo_, escrito en el 1950 aprox pero centrado en la Italia de los 1870.

Answer (score 4):

Este cambio de *c/s* a *ch* no es poco común<sup>[1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Spanish_diminutives_of_given_names) [2](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17631/why-is-paco-the-equivalent-of-francisco)</sup> en los diminutivos de nombres propios:

| Nombre | Diminutivos |
| --- | --- |
| Alfon**s**o | Pon**ch**o |
| Jo**s**efa | **Ch**epa |
| **S**er**g**io | **Ch**e**ch**o |
| Fran**c**isco | Pa**ch**o, Pan**ch**o |
| Mer**c**edes | Mer**ch**e, Me**ch**e |
| Vi**c**ente | Vi**ch**o |
| Con**c**epción | Con**ch**i, Con**ch**a, Con**ch**ita |

Es probable que la variante que termina en *-a* no se origine en dialectos en los cuales *concha* tiene un sentido vulgar.

Comment: Muy interesante, pero ¿por qué a _ch_? ¿Puede tener algo que ver que los niños aprenden antes a pronunciar la _ch_ que sonidos como _c_ (como en _Mercedes_) o _s_?

Comment: Por cierto, Mercedes suele convertirse en Merche, con _r_.